# Django Form Field for a list of strings

Tags: django, string, forms, list, django-forms

I need a **Django Form Field** which will take a list of strings.

I'll iterate over this list and create a new model object for each string.

I can't do a **Model Multiple Choice Field**, because the model objects aren't created until *after* form submission, and I can't do a **Multiple Choice Field**, because I need to accept arbitrary strings, not just a series of pre-defined options.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I came up with a solution -- a little hacky but it works for now.

After grabbing the form data, I stash the list in a variable:
`event_locations = form_data.get('event_locations', None)`

Then I remove it from form_data, so the Django Form never gets the list:

```
if event_locations:
   del form_data['event_locations']
```

I instantiate my form with form_data, and handle the list separately:

```
f = NewEventForm(form_data)
...
for loc in event_locations:
  #create new models here
```

I realize this doesn't directly solve the question I asked, because we still don't have a Django Form Field taking a list, but it's a way to pass in a list to a view that takes a form and be able to handle it.

Answer (score 8):

Just use a regular text field delimited by commas. After you handle the form submission in the view do a comma string split based on that field. Then iterate over each one creating and saving a new model. Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I considered this, but it would be a pretty big break with convention in my API.

Comment: I know this is a super old question, but do you know if this still the convention? It seems like they should have something built in for handling lists by now.

Answer (score 2):

In my case to process list of strings I used `forms.JSONField(decoder="array")` in my `forms.py` in form class